# Required package 'rtl' not found when installing components

Tags: c++builder

When installing TMS Software packages I suddenly got error "Required package 'rtl' not found"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several tries I found that in \bin\dcc32.cfg file the path to libraries had somehow got wrong drive: D:\Program Files\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7.0\lib instead of C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7.0\lib.
I have no idea how this happened. After fixing it the installation worked OK.